# configurable product show as out of stock in front end but In stock in back end

Tags: magento-1.7, configurable-product, inventory

The configurable product shows as out of stock in front end product details page. I checked its associated products, it contains 25 as quantity and status as In stock. Thus the drop down options are not showing in the product description page.

I've also done reindexing, still no changes

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all check the child products of the configurable product are inStock. If at least one child product is out of stock, this can cause to your problem.

Check your products are all attached to main websites.

Go to Manage Products > product > Website is in sidebar, check if it is unchecked

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've checked all the child products, all of them are "In stock" and Qty>0. But how can I check this -"Check your products are all attached to main websites.", Sorry I'm a beginner in magento.

Comment: Update my answer please check

Comment: Manage Products > product name(edit) and Could not find Website is in sidebar. Am I going in the wrong direction?

Comment: No, nothing wrong its just that you have only one store website view

Comment: OK, rename var folder on root to something else, say var--, and create a var folder with 777 permissions

Comment: No change. :( I used  http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-a-configurable-product - to create configurable product, I there anything I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

Check the following as well,

1. All child products should be "enabled ", "in stock" and quantity>0
2. The parent product enabled and "instock"
3. Go to the parent product, on the left hand menu, select "Associated products" and check if the simple products are associated with the configurable correctly.

Reindex and Clear cache, and try again. It should appear.