# Configurable products quantity always 0

Tags: magento-1.9, catalog, inventory, ce-1.9.2.1

I have created a configurable product and I have setted different associated simple products into "Associated Products" tab.

All the simple products have quantity >1, are In Stock, Available and linked to the Main Store (actually i have only one store).

After the first configuration, in the administration products grid, the quantity of the configurable product is the sum of all the associated products and the product is correctly shown in the front-end store.
After the sale of the product, in the administration products grid, the quantity of the configurable product is automatically set to 0, while the quantity of the sold associated product is correctly decreased.

Someone can help me to understand this problem?

I'm using Magento Magento ver. 1.9.2.1.

Comment: Here is the answer you are looking for:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/30752/4510

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is an issue I'm using a different version of magento but the configurable item will have stock 0 as you don't hold any stock of it, but it will decrement the child products stock when you purchase the configurable correctly, and display those as out of stock in the selector on the frontend if the child product becomes out of stock.